# ¿Porque SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth no funciona?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

Necesito hacer una captura de pantalla que incluya todas las pantallas y para eso usaba `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth` y `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight`.
Esto antes me funcionaba pero ahora ya no y no entiendo porque. He creado un proyecto aparte para probar pero tampoco funciona. El valor debería ser 1920 x 1080 pero es 1536 x864.

Este es mi código:

```
Bitmap imagen = new Bitmap((int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imagen);

g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new 
Size((int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight));

g.Dispose();
imagen.Save("imagen.bmp");
imagen.Dispose();
```

(el proyecto usa .NET 6.0)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** He probado el programa en otro ordenador y sorprendentemente en uno funciona pero en el otro no. No me explico porque ya que los dos funcionan con windows 10. De hecho falla en el ordenador que supuestamente es el más nuevo (especificamente tiene 3 semanas). ¿Alguien tiene alguna explicación de porque pasa esto?

No se sí tendrá algo que ver pero el ordenador donde no funciona es un portatil.

Comment: Cual de los dos da diferente... te fijaste en la documentacion si no dice nada sobre un cambio ¿

Comment: Da diferente en la versión .NET 6.0 y no he encontrado nada ni en la documentación ni en otras páginas. A lo mejor estoy haciendo algo mal al buscar